# Configured debug type 'hl' not supported

Tags: visual-studio-code, haxe, vscode-debugger

I have installed hash link on my linux machine (works on the terminal as expected) and upon pressing F5 from vscode for my heaps.io program, it says `Configured debug type 'hl' not supported`. So I tried searching for hashlink on the extensions market and found no results. I have copied my launch.json from the heaps.io tutorial website. What should I do?

### Launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "HashLink",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "hl",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "preLaunchTask": {
                "type": "haxe",
                "args": "active configuration"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

### Where the launch.json file can be found

https://heaps.io/documentation/hello-hashlink.html

Comment: Have you installed the Haxe extensions in VSCode? https://heaps.io/documentation/installation.html

Comment: @md2perpe yeah I have it installed.

Comment: @md2perpe ok I have now installed the .vsix extension of hashlink. But when I try to install it to vscode it gives an error saying: `Unable to install extension 'haxefoundation.haxe-hl' as it is not compatible with VS Code '1.65.0'.` Here is the extension link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HaxeFoundation.haxe-hl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I made it work! For some reason I had to copy all the required libraries from `/usr/local/lib` to `/lib64` for vscode to launch my application through hashlink.

Also about the hashlink, I just installed the .vsix version of hashlink of version `1.1.12`. The versions above that don't seem to work with the latest vscode version.